# What is the difference between creating a model instance using the default Manager and Customer Manager

Tags: django, django-models

While going through the official Django documentation I came across the Model Instance reference section in which it is mentioned that you can create an instance of the model using the custom Model using self.create. I wanted to know what's the difference between using the create method and the custom create_method when both are using the same fields and in both the cases the data is being saved in the DB.
Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        book = self.create(title=title)
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")

Difference between these two

book2 = Book.objects.create(title="Pride and Prejudice")
```

Comment: Well in this case there is no difference at all, of course. Your method just calls the original create method and returns the result. Why would you do this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, no apparent reason. I was bit confused with the part in the documentation where it is mentioned that you need to use the save method to touch the database. So I concluded that this method would not save in the DB till you use the save method. Although I know create method performs the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this simplest case, there is no difference. The reason of describing this technique in docs is obvious there

> **You may be tempted to customize the model** by overriding the __init__
>   method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
>   signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being
>   saved. Rather than overriding __init__, try using one of these
>   approaches:

It means you may be want to set some extra/default values to model instance. If you override constructor for this purpose, it is a little unsafe (and not usually a practice in django). That's why two other techniques for doing this are described. You are mentioning one of them. You can do some extra stuff in custom manager method if you want

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        # you can do some extra stuff here for instance creation
        book = self.create(title=title)
        # or here when it is saved to db
        return book
```

Otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: thanks for the help. Just wanted to know what does the documentation means when it says **" Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database; for that, you need to save()"** . This is the bit which was confusing to me as I assumed self.create wouldn't save in the DB, although I know it does.

Comment: It means simple instantiating an object for model M like `i=M(x=1, y=2)` does not insert it to db. `i.save()` does. `create` is part of `QuerySet` class and Manager is kind of wrapper around it. Think of `create` as a utility function  which performs above mentioned two steps to save a model instance to db. It passes all kwargs passed to it to model class attached to it to make an instance `i`, does `i.save()` and returns `i`. You can see the implementation of `create` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/query/#QuerySet). It is very clean and clear.